# How to compare object's type with a generics type, irrelevant to generic argument?

Tags: c#, generics

Best way to illustrate my question is with this example code:

```
  class Item {}
  class Container< T > {}
  class Program
  {
    static void DoSomething( object something )
    {
      if( typeof( Item ) == something.GetType() )
      {
        System.Console.WriteLine( "Item" );
      }
      else if( typeof( Container<> ) == something.GetType() )
      {
        System.Console.WriteLine( "Container<>" );
      }
    }

    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
      DoSomething( new Item() );
      DoSomething( new Container< int >() );
    }
  }
```

The following line will not work:

```
else if( typeof( Container<> ) == something.GetType() )
```

Is it a way to make it work without explicitly changing `Container<>` into `Container<int>`? I want to know that object is of 'Container' type and I really has no interest is it `Container<int>` or `Container<string>`. Any hints other than dozens lines of reflection?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try:

```
typeof(Container<>) == something.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition()
```

Note that this will only return true if the actual type is `Container<T>`. It doesn't work for derived types. For instance, it'll return `false` for the following:

```
class StringContainer : Container<string>
```

If you need to make it work for this case, you should traverse the inheritance hierarchy and test each base class for being `Container<T>`:

```
static bool IsGenericTypeOf(Type genericType, Type someType)
{   
  if (someType.IsGenericType 
          && genericType == someType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()) return true;

  return someType.BaseType != null 
          && IsGenericTypeOf(genericType, someType.BaseType);
}
```